# Fluid - vertically align all elements, two elements position left and right and one is on center

Tags: css

I have three images here:

I'm trying to accomplish: The one small image should be on left and the other small image should be in right. The bigger one should be in center. All of these images should be vertically aligned.

I tried to use `text-align` but it does not work:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/329HV/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_header_new">
    <img id="menu_info" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/849x565q90/833/uua2.jpg" />
    <img id="menu_logo" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/849x565q90/833/uua2.jpg" />
    <img id="menu_settings" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/849x565q90/833/uua2.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu_header_new {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    min-height:20%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;

}
#menu_logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu_info, #menu_settings {
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
}

#menu_info{
    text-align: left;
}

#menu_settings{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with text-align you have to add a line with an extra element or a pseudo element to trigger text-align:justify; on single line.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu_header_new {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    min-height:20%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:0.01px;
}
#menu_header_new:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#menu_logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu_info, #menu_settings {
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

Or you can use `display:flex;` see different test with `display` and `text-align`: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/nrbDl